# ssh connection to OSMC fails after giving the correct password

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, sshd

I have a freshly setup Raspberry Pi 3 with OSMC; I can't login via `ssh`.
I *can* open a shell when using my wireless keyboard, `sudo -s` works, and AFAICS, WiFi connection is fully functional, including DNS (which I verified by installing and using `nslookup`). I *can* `ssh` to my RasPi 1B with OpenElec (other machine, other OS, but same WiFi setup, using the same Fritz!Box and DHCP).

When I try to connect via `ssh` (both tried with PuTTY, and with a Ubuntu 14.04 netbook), I'm prompted for the user name, then for the password. After giving a wrong password, I'm prompted again; after giving the correct one, nothing happens anymore.  (PuTTY gives up after after 20 seconds: "Network error: Software caused connection abort").

This is a permanent problem; with this "machine" and this OS, it has never worked for me.

I enabled debugging mode in the `sshd` configuration, and I put some log excerpt to  http://termbin.com/0y7u. `journalctl -u sshd` didn't work (the output was empty), so I took the complete output and preserved all `sshd` lines and a few more. (will be online roughly until July 21st, 2016)

I first gave a wrong password (`20:41:45`), then the correct one (`20:41:48`).

Could the problem hide in the following final lines?

```
Jun 21 20:41:48 osmc sshd[777]: Starting session: shell on pts/0 for osmc from 192.168.178.26 port 52907
Jun 21 20:41:48 osmc sshd[778]: debug1: Setting controlling tty using TIOCSCTTY.
```

I assume it's another problem than [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235261/ssh-connection-closed-after-correct-login) because I don't have this `Received disconnect` line.

Any ideas? Thank you!

**Update**: `ssh -v osmc@osmc` gives me the following output:

```
...
debug1: Next authentication method: password
osmc@osmc's password:
debug1: debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Authenticated to osmc ([192.168.178.30]:22).
debug1: chennel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = de_DE.UTF-8
```

This didn't terminate, even after a few minutes of waiting; `ps a` in another terminal gave me:

```
 PID TTY   STAT  TIME  COMMAND
1324 tty1  Ss    0:00  /bin/login --
1508 tty1  S     0:00  -bash
1564 tty1  S+    0:00  ssh -v osmc@osmc
```

I couldn't terminate the `ssh` call by `Ctrl+C`; `kill 1564` worked, of course, and gave me two more lines:

```
debug1: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: Killed by signal 15.
```

**Update 2:** I meanwhile installed a fresh raspbian system on another chipcard which I put in the same machine.  Interestingly, I have the same problem; but when logged in with the wireless keyboard attached, I can do `ssh localhost` which works like a charm.

Now the original `OSMC` system won't boot anymore; perhaps it will after some sleep.  But now I suspect there might be a problem with the kernel changes for RasPi 3, since the `Raspbian` system didn't let me `ssh` in either.

Comment: What is the output with `-v` to your `ssh` command using the netbook?

Comment: you could try creating a new user with `useradd` from your sudo and logging in as that.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist: I updated my question with this information added.

Comment: @meuh: I created the new user, as suggested, and sadly this didn't help.

Comment: have you managed to do regular auto system updates, or on-demand in the osmc screen?

Comment: @meuh: Yes, no problem; the box can connect. `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` do work alright. The `ssh` login still doesn't work.

Comment: Check if it works doing `ssh localhost` on the server. But it seems this is not an ssh problem per se, but rather something about the login shell start.

Comment: @RalphRönnquist: I updated my question with some related info. Given `ssh@localhost` works - what would this imply?

Comment: It's peculiar :-) Could it be the LANG environment setting that confuses the server? Or is it something at network level, such as MTU? Or does the user login disturb the wifi connection?

Comment: I just got a pi 3, and downloaded osmc on it. I managed to ssh as user osmc. Note: I had LANG=C. The first login took a minute or so with *Updating APT cache. Please be patient.* After setting up keys, I can ssh without password too.